# Add condition by [attr.data-show] values in template

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-ng-if, angular-template

I am trying to implement a condition in template using `attr.data-show` attribute value. but it's not works. what is the correct way to handle this?

here is my code :

```
<p [attr.data-show]="false" *ngIf="{{this.attr.data-show}}">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

any one help me?

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gjbhca)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access a `-` separated poperty like: `attrOb['data-show']`

```
<p [attr.data-show]="false" *ngIf="attrOb['data-show']">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

This would also mean, that you have `attrOb` in `.ts`

```
attrOb: any = {
  'data-show': true
}
```

You can find your modified code here: [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hwbdeu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: No, I can't implement it. because the attribute supplied by server.

Comment: @3gwebtrain, that would be fine, what I mean is, that you need to have an access to something called `attrOb` in my example (`attr` in yours) either from API or directly initialized in your template.

Comment: But I am looking to map from `attr` value to condition, without ts interaction

Comment: @3gwebtrain Sorry, had missed your comment. If you are accessing a variable in your template and that variable should be populated through an API call, how do you think you would have the value of the variable in HTML if you do not have it in ts?

Comment: I am supplied the property file like `environment` file. from there I am directly appending in to attribute. it works. some time it has condition to apply in to template

Comment: @3gwebtrain The available variables in the scope of your HTML would your `.ts` and gloabal variables provided by Angular or JS. Apart from that if you can not acccess any variable which is not present in your `.ts`, think it this way. Would you be able to access a class property of one component into another unrelated component? If your data available in environment like file, then you need to import that file/variable in your ts

Comment: yes I agree. But I tried to minimize the work load.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not exactly sure what you're looking for. But to control the visibility of an element within a template, you could use `<ng-template>` to create embedded views and use their context properties. Try the following

```html
<ng-template #textShow let-show>
  <ng-container *ngIf="show">
    <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>

<ng-template 
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="textShow" 
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: true }"
></ng-template>
```

Now you could control the visibility using the property `$implicit: true` (show content) and `$implicit: false` (don't show content).

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xp7df2)